# Can't figure out a htaccess rule

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver, htaccess

I have this in my htaccess but can't figure out what its for.
Because of the nature of rule, searching doesn't help either.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

Can anyone please explain what its for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means :

- If it's not true (`!`) that either (`(|)`):

  - the URI ends with a slash (`/$`), or
  - the URI contains a point (`\.`),
- Then append a slash to the URI (`%{REQUEST_URI}/`), and
- Return the new URI to the client's browser with return code 301
  (`[R=301]`), which means permanent redirect to the new URI, and which also
  tells the browser to display the new URI in the address bar.